# JavaScript 2dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following

```
    var arrayT = new Array();
    arrayT['one'] = arrayT['two'] = new Array();
    arrayT['one']['a'] = arrayT['one']['b'] = '';
    arrayT['two'] = arrayT['one'];
    arrayT['two']['a'] = 'test';
    console.log(arrayT);
```

In console I have

```
    [one][a]='test'
    [one][b]=''
    [two][a]='test'
    [two][b]=''
```

Why?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGujc/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
arrayT['one'] = arrayT['two'] = new Array();
```

creates a *single shared array object*. Each "inner" array in your two-dimensional array is really just a reference to the same object, so altering one "inner" array will necessarily affect the other in the exact same way.

Instead, create two separate arrays:

```
arrayT['one'] = new Array();
arrayT['two'] = new Array();
```

***Futhermore***, even if you implement that change, the line:

```
arrayT['two'] = arrayT['one'];
```

will create the same problem -- `arrayT['two']` and `arrayT['one']` will point to the same object, possibly causing future problems of a similar nature (e.g., altering `arrayT['two']['a']` on the next line will alter `arrayT['one']['a']`, since they point to the same object).

Answer (score 3):

`arrayT['one']` and `arrayT['two']` are the same array, any change you make to one will affect the other.

To fix this, create separate arrays:

```
arrayT['one'] = new Array();
arrayT['two'] = new Array();
```

This issue of multiple references to the same array happens when you use `arrayT['one'] = arrayT['two'] = new Array()`, but `arrayT['two'] = arrayT['one']` will create the same issue.  To make `arrayT['two']` a copy of `arrayT['one']` you should use the following:

```
arrayT['two'] = arrayT['one'].slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

While apsillers is right with his answer, a more accurate replacement would be to simply write `arrayT['two'] = arrayT['one'].slice(0)`
leaving out the assignment to `arrayT['two']` in line 2.
Note, that this is only a shallow copy. Depending on your needs you might need to do a deep copy, if you should decide to use mutable objects later.